# Wrong element sizes on Samsung's browser

Tags: android, html, css, samsung-mobile

We have a sticky cookie notification at the bottom of a site. It looks fine on all other browsers, but Samsung's default browser called "Internet" displays it wrong, causing the text element to be much narrower than it should be. This results in an ugly line break, mispositioned dismiss button and unnecessary extraneous height for the sticky element.

[image: Screenshot on a Galaxy Note 3]

I don't know any good way to start solving this problem, since it only happens on Samsung's mobile browsers and I haven't found a way to run any CSS/DOM inspector on it.  Any ideas?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1m94d99o/4/

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.bottom-notifications {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.bottom-notification {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in, max-height 0.5s linear 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in, max-height 0.5s linear 0.3s;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.bottom-notification__content {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
}
    
.bottom-notification__text {
    padding: 15px 77px 15px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


.bottom-notification p {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.bottom-notification a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
}



.button, .bottom-notification__dismiss, .search-box-container .search, .wideunit__button a {
    border: none;
    border-width: 2px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in, border-color 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in, border-color 0.1s ease-in;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

.bottom-notification__dismiss {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 77px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .bottom-notification__content {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

    .bottom-notification__text {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    
    .bottom-notification a {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .bottom-notification__dismiss {
        position: relative;
        width: 45px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5em;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-notifications">
<div class="bottom-notification bottom-notification--any" id="notification-5d93762f1abe41aaa78ab86cb59cba7c">
    <div class="bottom-notification__content">
      <span class="bottom-notification__text"><p>By using this site you accept the use of cookies.&nbsp;<a href="http://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/" target="_blank">Read more</a></p>
</span>
      <button class="bottom-notification__dismiss" data-notificationid="5d93762f1abe41aaa78ab86cb59cba7c" data-cookiename="bulletinalert-14cd5c89c251a9cd882313850af757a10100d620">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug with an older version of the browser.

I couldn't replicate it on the S7 Edge running Samsung Internet v4.0 (Android v6.0.1):

[image: Screenshot]

However, I was able to replicate it with an S4 on Android 4.4.2, running Samsung Internet v1.5 - I used Samsung's [Remote Test Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action?os=101) for this:

[image: Screenshot]

Regarding how to debug the browser, there is a section about [remote debugging Samsung Internet here](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72) which I hope may be useful.